# Passing too many parameters from C# to Oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, oracle11g, system.data.oracleclient

I have created a REST API which will consume json data with 80+ key/value pairs. I want to save those 80+ keys and their values in an Oracle DB table. Right now I am planning to add all 80 parameters as Command parameter.

Is there any other way to do this?

And in the DB side, is there any other way to accept these input parameters together other than by mentioning 80 input parameters in the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Use Oracle collection as a single parameter. You can pass a large list of values there.
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS005